# Measuring download speed with ping

Tags: linux, networking, internet, download, ping

I know that ping is about the time elapsed during my internet connection sending a packet and receiving a response, and download speed is about how quick I can pull information from the server.

From command line, I first ran speedtest-cli and it printed 28.05 Mbit/s download speed. Then, I used the following command, which I have seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575537/calculate-upload-download-speed-by-ping):

```
sudo ping -f -c 500 -s 1472 111.222.333.44
```

and it printed

```
min/avg/max/mdev = 0.811/1.095/14.162/0.960 ms
```

So I divided 24Kbit (apparently 1472 somehow transforms into 1500, then 1500*2*8 gives 24000 because of 1500 sent and 1500 received bytes) by 1.095 ms and I obtained 21.9Mbit/s. The error percentage does not seem to be too much in my case. Is this a good and reliable way of measuring the download speed? If not, how can I measure the download speed without using tools like speedtest-cli and network monitoring tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not a good way to measure download speed. ICMP might have different priorities to normal traffic on a network (especially on company/carrier networks). It completely bypasses the TCP window mechanism, resulting in skewed results. Also some traffic shaping mechanisms cannot be reliably measured in this way (BSD `ipfw` takes a few seconds to kick in for example).

You will want to use a method that uses TCP, so for example HTTP or FTP as well as a relatively large stream (big file). There are a bunch of websites out there that offer binary files with random data, to test your download speed. Google for "speed test test file download" and you'll probably find a few. You can then use `curl` or `wget` to measure the throughput.

Comment: Best way to measure a local BW is to download a .torrent file with a very large number of seeders and then download the actual content.

Comment: It's a good way to gather a lot of bandwidth, however I've seen in the past that (cheaper) routers sometimes can't handle the large amount of concurrent connections in the state table and start slowing down (skewing the results). It's definitely something to try though.

Comment: Yes, for cheaper routers users must limit concurrent connections to an acceptable value for the router. If done correctly, performance of downloads is not affected.